# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable oop

Tags: python, oop

Im new to oop with python. Why am I getting this error? Shouldnt it print tom and 12?

```
  class Dog:
        def __init__(self,name,age):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
    
    
        def name(self):
            return self.name
    
        def age(self):
            return self.age
    
    
  dog = Dog("tom", 12)
    
  print(dog.name())
  
  print(dog.age())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a variable and `name` is also a function.

Therefore this error.

Just do `print(self.name)`

Comment: What do you recommend to fix the OP's problem?

Comment: can also rename `name` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instance attributes take precedence over class attributes when one of each exists and they have the same name. If you are going to have a method that returns the value of an attribute, a common convention is to make the name of the instance attribute a "private" version of the method name by prefixing an underscore to the name.

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def age(self):
        return self._age
```

However, until you have a good reason to hide the attribute behind a getter, just expose the attribute as part of the public interface.

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


d = Dog("tom", 12)
print(dog.name)
```

If you later decide to hide the attribute behind a getter and/or setter, you can use a property to do so without changing the public interface.

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, v):
        self._name = v


d = Dog("tom", 12)
print(dog.name)  # Works the same as before
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to create class and change the name of funtion like this

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def Name(self):
        return self.name

    def age(self):
        return self.age


dog = Dog("tom", 12)

print(dog.name())

print(dog.age())
```